# I would like to draw the first row of my dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image: dataframe]

I would like to have a plot for each case in my dataframe. my x-axis is a range between 10 and 500 and my y-axis is the row values of each column for each case (prob-10, prob-20 and so on up to prob-500)

what i really wants is to have a plot for example for case1
x-axis = 10  , 20 ,30 , .....
y-axis =  0,35, 0,24, 0,44 .....

my dataframe looks like this

| cases | year | HH | prob-10 | prob-20 | prob-30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| case1 | 2018 | 200 | 0,35 | 0,24 | 0,44 |
| case2 | 2017 | 299 | 0,33 | 0,25 | 0,33 |
| case3 | 2019 | 200 | 0,45 | 0,22 | 0,33 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set index to `cases`, this will ease the `df.plot` function later and [`filter`] only the columns starting with `prob-`. Convert the comma used in the original dataframe to dot so that the dataframe can be interpreted as `float` with `astype(float)`. Then, transpose the dataframe to get the y-axis with the row values of each column for each case, plot the chart with `df.plot(kind='bar')`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep='\s+')

df = df.set_index('cases')
# get only prob-* columns
df = df.filter(regex='prob-*')
# replace original comma with dot
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '.'))
df = df.astype(float)
df = df.T

df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image: barplot_cases]

Comment: this looks great but can i have it as scatter plot and for each case separately not in the same graph

Answer (score 1):

In case that you meant a row for a specific value of case you could try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import logging

df = pd.DataFrame({"cases": ["case1", "case_2", "case_3"],
               "year": ["2017", "2018", "2019"],
               "HH": [200, 299, 200],
               "prob-10": [0.35, 0.33, 0.45],
               "prob-20": [0.24, 0.25, 0.22],
               "prob-30": [0.44, 0.33, 0.33]})

def plot_row_as_bars(df: pd.DataFrame,
                 case: str="case1",
                 exclude_list: list=["cases", "year", "HH"]):
    """ Plot row of a Pandas dataframe as bar chart
    """
    temp = df.loc[df["cases"] == case]
    # Check temporary dataframe
    if len(temp) < 0:
        logging.warning(f"Case: {case} is not avialable.")
        return

    # Exclude columns
    temp = temp.drop(exclude_list, axis = 1)

    x = temp.columns
    y = temp.iloc[0].to_list()

    plt.bar(x, y)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

plot_row_as_bars(df)
```

[image]

Comment: what i really wants is to have a plot for example for case1 
x-axis = 10  , 20 ,30 , .....
y-axis =  0,35, 0,24, 0,44 .....

Comment: For a scatter plot just use plt.scatter(x, y) instead of plt.bar(x, y)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you mean by "draw the first row", but if you want to simply save the first row as a variable you could try casting the dataframe to a dictionary like this.

```py
row1 = dict(df)[0][1]
print(row1)
```